# Saving user input in React.js. If user inputs text in an input field, I want to save it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you save a text that user typed in reactjs?

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./ToDo.css";

const ToDo = () => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const HandleInputChange = (event) => {
        setInput(event.target.value);
    }

    const SaveInput = () => {
        setInput(document.innerText = input)
    }

    const DeleteInput = () => {
        setInput('');
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <input type={'text'} value={input} onChange={HandleInputChange}/>
            <button onClick={SaveInput}>✓</button>
            <button onClick={DeleteInput}>X</button>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <ul>
                <li>{input}</li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default ToDo;
```

I want to know how to save a user typed in a input and save it and display it to the user

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your question, you wanna save input into List Field. You first need to save input into Localstorage of browser and then mapping all input in the list...

Changes in code like-

```
const SaveInput = () => {
setInput(document.innerText = input)
}
```

in the above arrow function try to set localstorage with user input and also relaod the page onClick..
After saving input in localstorage now next step is to get value from then mapping it...
Hope above solution helping you in getting your result. If you still facing any issue just lemme know..
Thanks

Comment: I do not get what you mean by localstorage. Could you explain more? Thanks

Comment: LocalStorage is browser storage. You can check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/localstorage-in-reactjs for more. Also use localstorage on development while in production change localstorage with Database.